# While printing i dont want to display edit and delete column name

Tags: javascript, php

While printing the  pages I dont want to display edit and delete column name.please go through my code and help me.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

?>    
<tr>
            <td><?php echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime($row['date'])); ?></td>       
           <td><?php echo $row['receviername'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['receivercontactno'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['payeename'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['payeecontactno'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['purpose'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['category'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['amount'] ?></td>

        <?php $_SESSION["id"]=$row['SI_No'];?>
            <td><a href="updateexp.php?id=<?php echo $_SESSION["id"]; ?>" alt='edit'>Update</a></td> //in this line i dont want to display edit button while printing the page
            <td align="left"><a href="javascript:delete_id(<?php echo $row['SI_No']; ?>)"><img src="images/delete.jpg" alt="Delete" style="width:30px;height:30px;"/></a></td> //in this line i dont want to display delete button while printing the page
         </tr>
```

Comment: you can use jquery or javascript to  hide the buttons when u print the page

Comment: then send me the code.i dnt no.

Comment: This isn't a "send me the code" website.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using css. Add a class to the td that you don't want to be displayed when you print

```
@media print {
 .noPrint {
  display:none;
 }
}
```

And on the td you add class="noPrint"